# Calling events cross-threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono

I'm working on a class that looks like this:

```
public class MatchmakingService  {
    private bool working;
    private List<MatchmakingUser> matchmakingUsers;
    // ...

    public MatchmakingService()
    {
        matchmakingUsers = new List<MatchmakingUser>();
    }

    public void StartService () {
        var thread = new Thread(this.MatchmakingWork);
        working = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    void MatchmakingWork () {
        while (working)
        {
            // some work, match found!
            {
                  if(onMatchFound != null)
                      onMatchFound(this, new NewMatchEventArgs(matchmakingUsers[i], matchmakingUsers[j]);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally when a match is found I'd just fire up an event onMatchFound and call it a day, but since the thread of the service is different, and a subscriber to this event will be on a different thread -- how to handle that? I've read it's not safe to do so and if it's true then what are my alternatives?

Note: I'm not working with WinForms so no Control's Invoke shenanigans.

Comment: This depends on situation. By itself there is nothing wrong when event subscriber is on another thread (especially if you are not on UI platform and don't need to dispatch anything to UI thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is creating a queue. There are multiple ways to implement a queue. I would create a queue in the `MatchmakingService`

Use a queue to store the matches, the other thread must call the `RaiseEvents()` method to handle the queue. This means, the other thread should have a Timer/DispatcherTimer/While with a sleep etc...

Example:

```
public class MatchmakingService
{
    private bool working;
    private List<MatchmakingUser> matchmakingUsers;
    // ...

    // the queue
    private List<NewMatchEventArgs> _queue = new List<NewMatchEventArgs>();


    public MatchmakingService()
    {
        matchmakingUsers = new List<MatchmakingUser>();
    }

    public void StartService()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(this.MatchmakingWork);
        working = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    void MatchmakingWork()
    {
        while (working)
        {
            // some work, match found!
            {
                lock (_queue)
                    _queue.Add(new NewMatchEventArgs(matchmakingUsers[1], matchmakingUsers[2]));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseEvents()
    {
        NewMatchEventArgs[] copyOfQueue;

        // create a copy (bulk action)
        lock (_queue)
        {
            copyOfQueue = _queue.ToArray();
            _queue.Clear();
        }

        // handle the items
        if (onMatchFound != null)
            foreach (var item in copyOfQueue)
                onMatchFound(this, item); // indices are examples

    }

    public event EventHandler<NewMatchEventArgs> onMatchFound;

}
```

Comment: Hm I already had queue for requests so yeah this seems good, thanks!

Comment: especially the `// create a copy (bulk action)` is very usefull, it will create a copy of the queue and releases the queue for the working thread. This is also useful handling bulk actions. I always use this method when receiving messages from TCP/IP etc. or other async stuff (when Invoke/Dispatcher etc is not available)